# PowerShell DSC res does not exist

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have created a ps1 file with the DSC configuration and one for the LCM.
The MOF files were created successfully.
When I start the configuration, I get the following error:

> The PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_TeamsMeetingConfiguration from module
> <Microsoft365DSC,1.21.728.1> does not exist at the PowerShell module
> path nor is it registered as a WMI DSC resource.

The Config file looks as follows:

```
Configuration TeamsConfig2
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,Position=0)][ValidateNotNull()][System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$AdminCred
    )
    Import-DSCResource -ModuleName "Microsoft365DSC"
    Node localhost
    {
        TeamsMeetingConfiguration DemoMeetingConfiguration2
        {
            ClientAppSharingPort        = 50040;
            ClientAppSharingPortRange   = 20;
            ClientAudioPort             = 50000;
            ClientAudioPortRange        = 20;
            ClientMediaPortRangeEnabled = $True;
            ClientVideoPort             = 50020;
            ClientVideoPortRange        = 20;
            CustomFooterText            = "sdfs"
            DisableAnonymousJoin        = $False;
            EnableQoS                   = $False;
            GlobalAdminAccount          = $AdminCred;
            HelpURL                     = "https://github.com/Microsoft/Office365DSC/Help";
            Identity                    = "Global";
            LegalURL                    = "https://github.com/Microsoft/Office365DSC/Legal";
            LogoURL                     = "https://github.com/Microsoft/Office365DSC/Logo.png";
        }

    }
}
```

The Microsoft365DSC module is installed with version 1.21.728.1.

[image: DSCRes]

Get-DSCResource also finds the resource so I currently don't understand what the issue could be.

Comment: Where did you install the resource modules?

Comment: The Res Modules come with the main module for Microsoft365DSC. They are installed in the user scope. The $Env:PsModulePath contains both the user path in which the module is located and the machine path.

Comment: I meant to say; at which machines?